# bumping unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

What is the policy regarding "bumping" unanswered questions? Is this taboo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's sort of covered in the [faq](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> #### What if I don’t get a good answer?
>
> In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Of course bumping by *answering* them is the most awesome solution of all. :)

Feel free to [edit the questions you answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to make them more useful, as well.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find the FAQ, but I see it now up there in the tiny nav at the top.

Comment: @unf it's linked at the top, at the bottom, in the sidebar (twice) as you ask a question.. and every new user is directed to the faq. Try visiting this site in Google Chrome Incognito mode to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't get a good answer or any answer at all, you can always offer a bounty.  But updating a question with additional information and progress updates is also a way to gain notice.

Posting an update merely to "bump" your question would be discouraged.  Updating to provide an *actual* update, updating by providing an answer or solution, or updating by offering a bounty would be encouraged.

Comment: One day, perhaps I'll have enough rep to be able to offer a bounty, but I'm really just getting started on stack exchange sites and now wondering why I've never used them before!

Comment: The more you use it, the more reputation you'll gain.  And you can always ask in the comments for someone else to offer a bounty on your behalf.